# What is the answer to this syllogism? Why is option D incorrect?

Tags: logic

Q.   a. Some books are not reference books.
     b. All books are encyclopedias.

 
**A**       Some reference books are no encyclopedias
**B**       No reference books are encyclopedias
**C**       All reference books are encyclopedias
**D**       None of the above

Comment: $C$ is possible since $b$ states that "All books are encyclopedias."

Comment: All three answers below make the assumption that reference books are books. This is not good syllogistic reasoning (because it is using domain knowledge about the noun phrase "reference book"). The only valid syllogistic conclusion is that some encyclopaedias are not reference books. That isn't on the list, so $\bf D$ is the right answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All reference books are books, and hence encyclopedias. So $C$ is the correct answer.

Even without knowing the meaning of 'reference book' and 'encyclopedia', either $A$ or $C$ must be true. If $C$ is false, i.e. not all reference books are encyclopedias, then there must be a reference book that is not an encyclopedia, and $A$ is true.

Comment: Although either $A$ or $C$ must be _true_, I don't see how you can conclude _from this_ that either $A$ or $C$ is the correct answer (_i.e._ that either $a,b \vdash A$ or $a,b \vdash C$.)

Comment: "All reference books are books" is not justified by the antecedents of the syllogism. Some $A$ are not $B$ and all $A$ are $C$ does not entail all $B$ are $C$.

Comment: Even though it's not explicitly stated so, I think we can safely assume that all reference BOOKS are books.

Comment: But the question is about formal syllogistic reasoning, not about the meaning of the English words. Otherwise you could just "safely assume" that the answer is the one that is actually true of reference books and encyclopaedias in the real world, namely $\mathbf{A}$.

Comment: Your edit hasn't solved the problem. Yes, either $A$ or $C$ must be true, but the data do not tell us which. Why can't $A$ be true?

Answer (score 2):

If a. and b. are your premises,

Some books aren't reference books. If a reference book did exist, it would be a book. Since all books are encyclopedias we can conclude that all reference books are encyclopedias. Since C is a correct answer, one of them is true, so D (none of the above) is incorrect.

Comment: How do you know that some books aren't reference books?  This doesn't follow from $a$ and $b$.  And in any case this is irrelevant; what you seem to be using is the fact (not stated explicitly) that all reference books are books.

Comment: a = some books are not reference books

Comment: Oops, sorry for the typo.  What I meant was: "How do you know that some books _are_ reference books? ...."

Answer (score 1):

I came across this while asking the same question. However, though some of you say that the answer is C, the answer that the site (fibonicci) posted was A. Personally, I believe that it is D, only because I cannot speculate that a reference book is a book. For example, another syllogism stated that all crabs are horses. And another states that A. All dogs are brown; and B. All pitbulls are brown. However, the answer is not, "All pitbulls are dogs." We all know that pitbulls are, in fact, dogs. Anyway, A is certainly not correct because it is a possibility that while some books are not reference books, all reference books may still be books. And if this is the case, then all reference books are then encyclopedias. It could be only some reference books are books. If that is the case, then only some reference books are encyclopedias. In the end, the answer would either be C or D, though I do not think it would be wise to assume that reference books are automatically books, even though it says reference **books**.

Comment: Thank you for posting the only correct answer so far! The answer on the fibonicci site is just plain wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose the Encyclopedias are E<sub>1</sub> , E<sub>2</sub> , ... E<sub>n</sub>.

Suppose the Books are  B<sub>1</sub> , B<sub>2</sub> , ..., B<sub>m</sub>.

Suppose the Reference Books are R<sub>1</sub> , R<sub>2</sub> , ..., R<sub>p</sub>.

Since all books are encyclopedias are books then there does not exist any   B<sub>i</sub> which is not same as 
    E<sub>j</sub> for all i and j.(Remember it is not vice-versa as some Encyclopedias may not be books according to the conditions provided.)

Now some  Books are no Reference Books.If all books are encyclopedias all reference books are books then all reference books are encyclopedias.Thus I believe Option-C is the correct option.